# Is it Possible to Access an Object Name from the Constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, object

So my question is if it's possible to access the name of the object being constructed, from the constructor function. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
Monk::Monk(int stam, int agil, string spec){
    stamina = stam;
    agility = agil;
    specialization = spec;
    cout << "'s Health is " << health() << endl;
    cout << "'s DPS is " << damage() << endl;
    cout << "'s current specification is a " << specName() << " monk." << endl;
}
int main() {
    Monk Tyler(25000, 1245, "Brewmaster");
    Monk Jackson(12500, 3000, "Windwalker");
    return 0;
}
```

So basically, if you look at the `cout` functions at the end of my constructor I would want the statements to begin with the names of the objects without hard coding. So for example, one of the objects is named `Tyler` I would want the first `cout` statement to print out `Tyler's Health is XYZ`.

I would like this to work so that I would just be able to create an object and not have to hardcode the name every time.

I'm sorry if this was a bad explanation of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: then you need to give a property name of every object: ***Monk::Monk(int stam, int agil, string spec, string name)***

Comment: Once the source has passed through the compiler, the "names" (C++ symbols) no longer exits. If you want to give your objects a specific name then you have to explicitly add such a property to your classes.

Comment: I was thinking that just creating a new property was probably the most practical way to do it, but I was just seeing if there is a better solution.

Comment: Objects don't have names. What you mean is "is it possible to access the name of the variable which refers to the object being constructed from the constructor". (And the answer's "no", unless you pass it in separately as a string).

Comment: What would be the names of temporaries or dynamically created objects or array members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that kind of instrocpection or reflection is kind of hard in C++

the best you can do is modify the class and  give a property name of every object:

```
Monk::Monk(int stam, int agil, string spec, string name){
    stamina = stam;
    agility = agil;
    specialization = spec;
    monkName = name;
    cout << monkName << "'s Health is " << health() << endl;
    cout << monkName << "'s DPS is " << damage() << endl;
    cout << monkName << "'s current specification is a " << specName() << " monk." << endl;
}

int main() {
    Monk Tyler(25000, 1245, "Brewmaster");
    Monk Jackson(12500, 3000, "Windwalker");
    return 0;
}
```

---

a side note, remember you can do

```
Monk::Monk(int stam, int agil, string spec, string name):stamina(stam),agility (agil),specialization(spec),monkName(name){
    //stamina = stam;
    //agility = agil;
    //specialization = spec;
    //monkName = name;
    cout << monkName << "'s Health is " << health() << endl;
    cout << monkName << "'s DPS is " << damage() << endl;
    cout << monkName << "'s current specification is a " << specName() << " monk." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use `this-> monkName` rather than just `name`. Also, as far as your second snippet is it more practical to put everything into the arguments or does it really make much of a difference?

Comment: In this example, there is no need for `this->`.   There are cases where it is required, for example in templates to force an expression to be dependent, but this isn't one of them.    Beyond that, it is generally better practice to pass everything to a function using arguments, and also to use an initialiser list in constructors.